# How to load an image using image url having arabic text in imageName Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsurl

How to get an image to load into **UIImageView**.

My **ImageUrl** looks like this

http://sample.com/image/data/SK08(ظ_*ظêّظéشظ*_).jpg

How is it Possible to load the image with the **Arabic text**?

Comment: Did you check the URL? It gives error 404.

Comment: @Amar I have mentioned ImageUrl look like this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to encode url like this

```
newString = [myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```